# Несоответствие версий php

Tags: php, openserver

В Openserver включаю php7, но когда в консоли ввожу php -v, выдаёт php 5.6, если же создать файл и вывести функцию phpinfo() то показывает версию php 7. Собственно из за этого я не могу установить v8js, так как она требует php 7. Что делать в такой ситуации и откуда берётся php 5.6?

Или может можно как то указать для какой версии устанавливать расширение или путь к ней?

Comment: Apache какой стоит? для семерки 2.4 нужен.... там вообще есть в настройках apache-7 и apache-7-x64, который надо для php7 использовать, может дело в нем. Хотя то, что phpinfo показывает верную версию,а консоль старую - довольно странно

Comment: именно apache-7 я и использую, обычный 2,4 не работает

Comment: Странно, конечно можно посмотреть пути в файлах, но имхо проще переустановить. openserver, чтоб не геморроится. Взять самую последнюю версию и переставить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenServer просто переставляет версию для Apache2. Для изменения версии php в консоли необходимо изменить путь с php-5.6 на путь к php-7.0 в переменной среды Windows "path".

Comment: Как вариант, писать путь к нужной версии php напрямую, вроде
C:\OpenServer\modules\PHP-7.0\php.exe myscript.php